# Descargar archivo en en mi equipo y no en el servidor con "file_input_create" de php

Tags: php

Como puedo descargar un archivo creado con file_input_contents en mi pc y no en el servidor.

Código file_input_contents

```
 $fichero = 'gente.txt';
 file_put_contents($fichero,'content');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Esto para forzar la descarga de tu archivo.
    $fichero = 'gente.txt';
    file_put_contents($fichero, 'content');

    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=gente.txt");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($fichero));

    $fp = fopen($fichero, "r");
    fpassthru($fp);`
```

Así lo he utilizado en algún proyecto.

Comment: Correcto, tienes razón.
Corrijo la respuesta que dí